# How to get Comma Separated Values From User input Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, datatable

I want to get user inputs from Textfeilds Like This

[image: Output Example Image]

Perform Multiplication with 1st and 2nd user input Like => P(x)*x

Also, Need
Sum of 1st User Input
Sum of 2nd User Input
Sum of 1st & 2nd Multiplied result

Print All data into the table Like Final output Image

[image: Final Out put]

Please Guide Me

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to convert the string of the user input into a list of numbers.
- You do this by splitting the string of user input by `,`.
- The above will give you a list of string, without the commas.
- You need to convert these strings into doubles.
- Now you can perform operations on them.

```
String userInput = '2,2,2';
List<double> listOfNumbers = userInput.split(',').map((e) => double.parse(e)).toList();
double result = 1;
//The below is assuming you want to multiple them with each other. But you can basically now perform any operations them.
listOfNumbers.forEach((e) => result = e * result);
print(result); // => prints 8
```